# Python + Scipy: How to set the time frame for a spectrogram?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, spectrum

I'm trying to calculate the spectrogram for an audio signal using [`scipy.signal.spectrogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html). As a project specification it is needed that the time frames be spaced 20ms from each other, but I can't find a way to set it.

The maximum value I was able to get was a non-exact 5ms after tweaking `noverlap` a bit.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said *"it is needed that the time frames be spaced 20ms from each other"*.  I'll assume that means the delay between the start of each window (or "segment") is 20 ms.

The three relevant parameters are `fs`, `nperseg` and `noverlap`.  `nperseg` is the number of samples in each "segment".  That is, it is the number of samples in the "window" that slides over the input data.  `noverlap` is the number of samples in the overlap of consecutive windows.  Therefore, the delay between success windows is `nperseg - noverlap` samples.

You want the window to move 20 ms, which corresponds to `fs*20/1000` samples (assuming `fs` is measured in samples per second, i.e. Hz).
Suppose your window length is T ms.  Then `nperseg` is `fs*T/1000`.
You want the overlap to be T-20 ms, and so `noverlap = int(fs*(T-20)/1000)`.